# How to generate class from nested maps

Tags: sass

I'd like to create classes for the basic font-setting with SASS. I've allready managed that I can @include my $font-types from the nested maps in any class, including responsive media-queries. My goal is now to automaticly create a class for each font-type in the map $font-types wich contains the settings defined in the nested map. How can I achieve that?

Here is my current Sass-File:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/d57a840259a9a01bf895

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function to dynamically create classes from lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975811/function-to-dynamically-create-classes-from-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/cc95352f47cbaff9975b

```
$stylethemes: (
    lead-1: (
    font-family: Arial,
    font-size: 30px, 
    font-size-md: 20px, 
    font-size-sm: 12px,
    ),
    lead-2: (
    font-family: Arial,
    font-size: 18px, 
    font-size-sm: 10px
    ),
);


@each $theme, $properties in $stylethemes {
  .#{$theme} {
    @each $prop, $val in $properties {

      @if $prop == font-family  {
        #{$prop}: $val;
      }
      @if $prop == font-size  {
        #{$prop}: $val;
      }
      @if $prop == font-size-md  {
        @include size-m {
          font-size: $val;
        }
      }
      @if $prop == font-size-sm  {
        @include size-s {
          font-size: $val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can expand your "stylethemes" and add other font-sizes for specific breakpoints with @includ.